# Test material-ui Button text

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, enzyme

I have a material UI button and I want to write a test to check if it rendered with the right test. I've tried

`expect(wrapper.find('.btn-class').text()).toBe('Next')`

but it fails with:

```
Expected: "Next" 
Received: "<Button />"
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `.value()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: @Eugene that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

`expect(wrapper.find(".btn-class").prop("children")).toEqual("Next");`

It is always better to avoid render.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I came up with

`expect(wrapper.find('.btn-class').render().text()).toBe('Next')`